# Make positive numbers evaluate to true and negative to false

Tags: javascript

I'm playing around in javascript and I am wondering if you could make all
values greater than -1 evaluate to true and all values from -1 and down evaluate to false?

Right now `1 == true` and everything else equals false if you write it like this:

```
var i = 0;
if (i) {...} // I want this to be true

i = 1;
if (i) {...} // This is the only thing that is true
```

EDIT: With evaluate I mean that I don't runt a comparison, e.g. `0 > -1`.
I want JavaScript to coerce the number into a boolean value.

Comment: What's the point? Is `i > -1` really that hard to write? Do not forget you can store the result of the expression in a variable. You could also write your own custom boolean conversion function, which would yield the desired result.

Comment: @plalx There isn't really a point, I am just playing around.

Answer (score 1):

you mean this?

```
if ( i > -1 ) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: I really don't think this is an answer to the question being asked.

Comment: OP wants 0 to be false, in your solution 0 is true.

Comment: @putvande OP said "all values greater than -1 evaluate to true"

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't change that, because it's built into the way the JavaScript `==` operator coerces values between types.

If you have [a loose equality expression](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) (`==`) where one of the operands is a boolean (`true` or `false`) and the other is a number, the JavaScript engine will try to convert the boolean into a number and will compare the result. [`true` converts to `1`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) if you try to convert it to a number, and so that's why `1 == true`.

Comment: @kjelelokk: You can't, it's built into the language rules. JavaScript doesn't have operator overloading, and you can't change the result of the abstract `ToNumber` operation on `true`.